# How to use params of object in Action

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

While creating a UI system, I am trying to create a UI event handler that takes a variable length parameter and performs an action.

Here is my code

```
class UIEventTriggerManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static UIEventTriggerManager Instance;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }

    public void Publish(string key, params object[] args)
    {
        m_eventHandler[key]?.Invoke(args);
    }

    public void Subscribe(string eventName, Action<object[]> action)
    {
        if (m_eventHandler.ContainsKey(eventName) == false)
        {
            m_eventHandler.Add(eventName, action);
        }
        else
        {
            m_eventHandler[eventName] += action;
        }
    }
}
```

```
class CharacterUI
{
    public void FirstOpen()
    {
        UIEventTriggerManager.Instance.Subscribe("ChagedCharacter", ChagedCharacter); // ChagedCharacter error

        UIEventTriggerManager.Instance.Subscribe("ChagedCharacter2", ChagedCharacter2); // error

        UIEventTriggerManager.Instance.Subscribe("ChagedCharacter3", ChagedCharacter3); // error
    }

    public void ChagedCharacter()
    {
         //....
    }

    public void ChagedCharacter2(int a)
    {
         //....
    }

    public void ChagedCharacter3(int a, string b, float c)
    {
         //....
    }

}
```

How to use Subscribe 'ChangedCharacter' Method??

Do I have to add 'params object[] args' to the method argument??

I know syntax error but I need an event handler to manage multiple parameters.

I'm trying to implement it this way, please give me some advice.

Comment: UIEventTriggerManager.Instance.Subscribe("ChagedCharacter3", (obj) => ChagedCharacter3((int)obj[0],(string)obj[1],(float)obj[2]));
this can work . but not good. beacuse it's new a action on every Subscribe , and it's have boxing unboxing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`params`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) does only exist in the signature of

```
Publish(string key, params object[] args)
```

meaning you can call this method with additional parameters - or not. Inside this method it is simply an `object[]` of variable length. If no args was passed in at all it will simply be an empty array.

Also yourself already seem to know that `Action<object[]>` simply takes an `object[]` - no `params` here.

[`Action<object[]>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.action-1) basically is nothing else than a shorthand for

```
public delegate void SomeName(object[] args);
```

Therefore also the listener method is simply

```
// Should it be "Changed" btw?
public void ChagedCharacter(object[] args)
```

and it is the responsibility of this (and any listener) to correctly handle the array.

The error should actually tell you exactly which signature `ChagedCharacter` was expected to have.

You could then e.g. do

```
private void ChagedCharacter(object[] args)
{
    switch(args.Length)
    {
        case 0:
            ChagedCharacter ();
            break;

        case 1 when args[0] is int intValue :
            ChagedCharacter (intValue);
            break;

        case 3 when args[0] is int intValue && args[1] is string stringValue && args[2] is float floatValue:
            ChagedCharacter (intValue, stringValue, floatValue);
            break;

        default:
            break;
            
    }
}
```

But honestly before you do that you rather overthink your design ...

Comment: Thank you. Seeing that there is a problem with the design. So I changing the design by using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this solution is enough for you. and this solution also have boxing unboxing , So maybe can use `<T>` to replace object[] to avoid.

```
public enum EventType
{
    ChagedCharacter,
    ChagedCharacter2
}

public class UIEventTriggerManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static UIEventTriggerManager Instance;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }
    static Dictionary<EventType, List<IReciveEvent>> recives = new Dictionary<EventType, List<IReciveEvent>>();

    public void Publish(EventType key, params object[] args)
    {
        if (recives.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            foreach(IReciveEvent ir in recives[key])
            {
                ir.GetEvent(key,args);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Subscribe(EventType type , IReciveEvent ui)
    {
        if(!recives.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            recives[type] = new List<IReciveEvent>();
        }

        if(!recives[type].Contains(ui))
        {
            recives[type].Add(ui);
        }
    }
}

public interface IReciveEvent
{
    void GetEvent(EventType type, object[] objs);
}

public class CharUI : MonoBehaviour, IReciveEvent
{
    private void Awake()
    {
        UIEventTriggerManager.Instance.Subscribe(EventType.ChagedCharacter, this);
        UIEventTriggerManager.Instance.Subscribe(EventType.ChagedCharacter2, this);
    }

    public void GetEvent(EventType type, object[] objs)
    {
        if(type == EventType.ChagedCharacter)
        {
            //todo
        }
        else if ( type == EventType.ChagedCharacter2)
        {
            int a = (int)objs[0];
            //todo
        }
        //....
    }
}
```